# Default app receives error on ripple emulation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I've just downloaded an extension for creating multi-device-hybrid-apps for Visual Studio 2013.
Before I've created a new project I've installed everything that's needed (Android SDK, ant, git cli, etc.)

Now, when I've created a blank app in Visual Studio, and ran it using ripple (nexus galaxy), I get the emulator and in the screen it says "Cannot GET /index.html".

The address shown in the address bar is localhost:4400/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0-NexusGalaxy.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the contents of your Build Output window?

Comment: the build is successful, but it doesn't find index.html

Comment: Set your build output to diagnostic (Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run\MSBuild project build output verbosity) and then rebuild.  You should see something like this in your build output window: "Starting launch process C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" followed by the path to ripple.js in your npm\node_modules\vs-mda folder and then the path under the bld folder of the debug contents being deployed to Ripple.  Inspect the contents of that folder and verify index.html exists.

Comment: @Ellen sorry, can't find such line in the output window

Comment: What do you see in the output window?  Can you share that?  If you are using the earlier version of our tools, you can try installing the new version that we just released.  It is very important that you first uninstall the previously released CTP2.0 from Programs and Features, then install VS 2013 Update 4, and then install VS Cordova Tools CTP3.0.  No need to remove any of the 3rd party dependencies though.  Here is a [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=397606) to the download center where you can find more information on installing the latest update.

Comment: @Ellen GREAT!! I've installed the update 4 and ctp3.0 and it worked!! You earned the bounty. Please write down an answer so I can award it to you. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @Ellen damn it's expired. sorry and thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem. It seems that sometimes VS2013 does do not recompile the app after a Clean...

I deleted my AndroidManifest.xml, did a Clean, then a manual Rebuild, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks!  Even after doing a "Clean" and deleting the "bld" folder, doing a "Build" doesn't copy the bits correctly, you have to do a *Rebuild* as you said.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted the "bld" folder in the file explorer of my solution. Then rebuild the solution and it works again

Answer (score 0):

Check the page name specified in your config.xml file exists.  Config.Xml --> Common --> Start Page

Answer (score 0):

I saw that error and needed to use the full project path at the command line: ripple emulate --path c:\project\myhello\platforms\android\assets\www

It worked after I used the full path.  Hopefully that helps you out from VS as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had some missing files in my android folder. I'm unsure how that happened, but this fixed the problem.

Open a command prompt at the project folder and enter:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

Then open VS 2015 and run Clean, then Rebuild.